# Reusable Dynamic Taxonomy Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, taxonomy

Ok, I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and hours on Google, but I just can't seem to get this to be dynamic. I have a shortcode that spits out an unordered list of taxnonomy terms associated with my Custom Post Type, but currently I have to copy & paste for each taxonomy term I want to show. I am trying to figure out how to make it dynamic in the way I can just use the same shortcode and just "pass in" a different taxonomy term.

```
function list_bar_location_taxonomy( $atts ) {

  global $post;

  $taxonomy = 'location';
  $locations = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );


  if ( ! empty( $locations ) && ! is_wp_error( $locations ) ) {
    $output = '<ul class="location-meta">';

    foreach( $locations as $location ) {
        $output .= '<li>';
        $output .= $location->name . '</li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';
  }

  return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'bars_location', 'list_bar_location_taxonomy' );
```

I want the taxonomy term 'location' to be interchangeable so I can pass in whatever taxonomy to be used and displayed on the front-end. e.g. taxterm2, taxterm3, etc.

I tried the following to no avail:

```
function list_bar_location_taxonomy( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( 
    array( 
      'custom_taxonomy' => ' '
    ), $atts
  );

  global $post;

  $locations = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $atts[ 'custom_taxonomy' ] );


  if ( ! empty( $locations ) && ! is_wp_error( $locations ) ) {
    $output = '<ul class="location-meta">';

    foreach( $locations as $location ) {
        $output .= '<li>';
        $output .= $location->name . '</li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';
  }

  return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'bars_location', 'list_bar_location_taxonomy' );
```

Any insight as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried your second code, and it is working fine for me. For example I created a custom-post-type with the slug  `customtype`, I created a custom-taxonomy for this post-type with the slug `customtax`, I added multiple post to this type and added some terms, `custom-term-1`, `custom-term-2`, `custom-term-3`. I inserted the shortcode `[bars_location custom_taxonomy="customtax"]` into one of these custom posts. On the frontend I can now see an unordert list with the 3 terms associated with that post, e.x. `Custom Term 1`, `Custom Term 2`, `Custom Term 3`. What is not working for you?

Comment: The shortcode will work without the [custom_taxonomy="customtax"] appended to it. All is needed is [bars_location] with either block of code.

The end goal is to be able to switch out "customtax" for other taxonomy terms using the same shortcode. e.g.

`[bars_shortcode custom_taxonomy="customtax-location"]`
`[bars_shortcode custom_taxonomy="customtax-types-of-bars"]`
`[bars_location custom_taxonomy="customtax-someothertaxonomy"]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the solution and have it working to where I can swap out the attribute for the shortcode with any taxonomy available associated with every post type:

```
function custom_taxonomy_list_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'term' => 'location', //Set whatever default taxonomy you like
  ), $atts );

  global $post;

  $custom_taxonomy = $atts['term']; // Assign it to a var
  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $custom_taxonomy );

  if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $output = '<ul class="cpt-term-list">';
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $output .= '<li>';
        $output .= $term->name . '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
  }
  return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'term-list', 'custom_taxonomy_list_shortcode' );
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```